# Grails: Iterate the day in new Date()

Tags: date, grails, groovy

does anybody know how to iterate the day of the date?
ie. something like

```
    new Date()+1
```

or

```
    new Date().format('yyyy-MM-dd')++;
```

or something like that?
Please let me know.

Comment: Did you try either? The first should work

Comment: I did but it has an error in grails console plugin. I used it to execute codes, ei. for loop the date and iterate the day for each loop.

Comment: Posting the code you tried and the error you got would help. The first should work

Answer (score 5):

Groovy has some elegant ways to work with date and time values, for example you can use [TimeCategory](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/time/TimeCategory.html).

```
import groovy.time.TimeCategory

use (TimeCategory) {
    new Date() + 1.day
}
```

Comment: TimeCategory is fantastic for date math

Answer (score 3):

For example:

```
def date = new Date()
```

you can use

```
date + 1
date.plus(1)
date.next()
```

reference: http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/util/Date.html

Answer (score 2):

You can also construct Ranges from Dates like so:

```
Date now = new Date().clearTime()
Date twoDaysTime = now + 2

(now..twoDaysTime).each {
  println it
}
```

Which will print:

```
Mon Aug 13 00:00:00 BST 2012
Tue Aug 14 00:00:00 BST 2012
Wed Aug 15 00:00:00 BST 2012
```